# playing audio stream in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am doing an audio playing Application in blackberry.When i pass a live url stream,it works,but when my url is a fixed one of size say 50 mb.It shows error,can anyone tell me the reason for it?

Comment: i debugged and saw in console

Comment: mediaError():MEDIA_LOADED (net.rim.device.internal.media.MediaPlayer@6648746d)
---mediaError():MEDIA_LOADED (net.rim.device.internal.media.MediaPlayer@6648746d)
+++unload():MEDIA_LOADED (net.rim.device.internal.media.MediaPlayer@6648746d)
MEDIA_PLAYER(0): Setting state to:MEDIA_UNLOADING (net.rim.device.internal.media.MediaPlayer@6648746d) from:MEDIA_LOADED (net.rim.device.internal.media.MediaPlayer@6648746d)
MN: unload0(0)=2 pauseHandle=0
MN: unload0(0) (clearing active pause)
MN: MEDIA_STOPPED received
MN: handle=0 staticsHandle=0
+++unloadCleanup():MEDIA_UNLOADING

Comment: any idea?it happens when the url is a fixed audio,but when its a livestream,it gets played

Comment: Edit your question and post the code y ou are using + the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to buffer and play the media using custom buffer class or just trying to pass url of media file to player.

if you pass url of media directly (not a streaming link but an mp3 file link for example) then device will try to download the file and then play the file and blackberry has 2 or 1 MB file size limit to download a file.

any how unless you paste some code here it is hard to answer your exact query. I also like to share this link for streaming media over internet.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255